# Removing and adding indentation in option on select

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Currently, I am setting indentations to the  tags in a  element to create a hierarchy.

```
<select>
    <option> Option 1 </option>
    <option> &nbsp;&nbsp;Option 2 </option>
    <option> &nbsp;&nbsp;Option 3 </option>
    <option> Option 4</option>
<select/>
```

However, when selecting Option 2, there is this awkward space in the front of it when compared to Option 1. This space gets much more noticeable when I go deeper into the hierarchy.

[image: Option 1] vs  [image: Option 2]

I already have a way to remove the space when the option gets displayed, but I need to be able to add it back when the select drop-down gets shown again.

Edit: I have played around with optgroup, but there is always the problem of having an extra space for the blank label.

Comment: what is the final output you want it look like?

Comment: The select drop-down should look normal, i.e. looks like a hierarchy with the indentations. Selecting an option should display it in the select box, but without the spacing.

Comment: Difficult to do, see [*Indenting HTML <select> options*](http://blog.christopherschultz.net/index.php/2009/02/10/indenting-html-select-options/) (off-site resource).

Answer (score -1):

Try using &emsp instead of a no-break space. This way, the selected option won't be displayed with space on the left. This isn't compatible on some older browsers though.

Comment: This would better be suited as a comment, not an answer. I understand that you have too little reputation to comment, but we all had to start from somewhere. Try editing posts to make them more readable and/or improve them. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Genuine question - was what I posted too brief, not directly addressing the OP's problem, or simply worded wrong? Why wasn't it a good answer? I will read the guidliness. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean that your suggestion is bad. I meant that answers of the type "try doing that maybe it will work better", are better suited for comments. Using `&emsp` will still make the selected option appear with white-space on the left.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, one way to remove   onchange select, and onclick select add   again on your option, where you want to add extra space. But this will be difficult handle.

other tip to use.

```
<select>
    <option> Option 1 </option>
    <option> &emsp;Option 2 </option>
    <option> &emsp;Option 3 </option>
    <option> Option 4</option>
<select/>
```

have a look on codepen created for you:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZXoBK

enjoy cheers